# Triggering Jenkins Job with dynamically choosing the node using jenkins-cli.jar

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

Need to trigger a jenkins job using cli with node as argument 
This can be accomplished using node and label parameter plugin using which we can pass nodename as a value to a defined parameter through cli. But is there any option to pass node name through commandline?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to trigger a Jenkins job by passing node as parameter is by installing node and label parameter plugin. As we can pass node as parameter we can trigger using command "java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http:jenkinsurl build jobname -p parameter_name= node_name"